# script to copy directory to another different directories

Tags: unix

I am trying to write a script to copy one directory into another different directories. I wrote the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

dir = "."
for f in "$dir"/*; do
    cp -r  Source "$f"
done
```

When I run this script, it tries to copy the "Source" directory on the system directories:

> cp: cannot create directory ‘/bin/Source’: Permission denied
>
> cp: cannot create directory ‘/boot/Source’: Permission denied   cp:
>   cannot create directory ‘/dev/Source’: Permission denied
>
> cp: cannot create directory ‘/etc/Source’: Permission denied
>
> cp: cannot create directory ‘/home/Source’: Permission denied

Any tips to make this script run on the current folder ?

Comment: What does your command `cp -r  Source "$f"` supposed to do? you haven't specified the target path.

Comment: Are you sure you want your script to run on the root directory?

Comment: No, I don't need to run it on the root directory. I want to run it under HW5 directory for example